# SOCKET | PYTHON | how to receive one message(?) at a time

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

So I am trying to make this 2 player online game, so I coded to send first client's snake position to server and server send that data to second client and do the same for second client. But when the client receives the position, the client get more than one position.
To make it clear, I will explain with the code

```
all_sprite = pg.sprite.Group()

class Opponent(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.group = all_sprite
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.group)
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill((155,155,155))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
tLock = threading.Lock()
#to receive the data
def recv():
    while True:
        with tLock:
            data = str(sock.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
            try:
                a,b = map(int, data.split())
                print(a,b)
                o.rect.x = a
                o.rect.y = b
            except:
                if data == "ok":
                    o = Opponent()
                else:
                    print(data)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 6666))

sThread = threading.Thread(target=recv)
sThread.daemon = True
sThread.start()  


# To send the data
class Sending(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.lock = threading.RLock()
        self.socket = s
        super(Sending, self).__init__()
    def setxny(self,x,y):
        with self.lock:
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
    def run(self):
        while True:
            with self.lock:
                a,b= str(self.x),str(self.y)
                self.socket.send(bytes(a+" "+b, 'utf-8'))
send_thread = Sending(sock)
send_thread.daemon=True
send_thread.start()

while RUNNING:
    send_thread.setxny(snakehead.rect.x,snakehead.rect.y )
    clock.tick(1)
    for event in pg.event.get():
if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            RUNNING = False
.....after this it's all about pygame so i will not include it
```

To check if the client was recieving the correct snake position, I coded to print the data when the client receive the data and the output was this

```
100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100 480100
```

and this is what i wanted to see...

```
100 480
```

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: There are no messages with TCP sockets since this is a streaming protocol. If you want messages you must insert your own message boundaries.

Comment: @quamrana, do you not think that's a full-blown answer, rather than a comment?

Comment: It's just hard to get a message (which message is right for you?) But if the last incoming message is the same as the previous one, you can ignore it.

Comment: Additional information: You should manage buffer memory very well in socket applications, such as clearing memory before receiving messages.

Comment: @palivek I wasn't sure that the idea of messages was what the OP was after, but that a comment might prompt some additional information.

Comment: @quamrana it"s not really a message actually i just need to get data.and how can i manage buffer memory??

Comment: How many times are you sending the data? To me each time you send the data, that's a message.

Comment: it's not a message. the client will send the position of the snake every time the snake moves

Comment: @HIYUM, are you sure it's _every time the snake moves_, not every frame? Right now your output is a row of the same exact coordinates, so it doesn't move.